# Adding dataframes that share the same columns, and expand one more dimesion

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to sum two dataframes that share the same columns

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3),index=list("ABC"),columns=list("XYZ"))
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3),index=list("abc"),columns=list("XYZ"))
```

My desired result would be:

```
    X Y Z
A a 
A b
A c 
....
C c
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried the following but didnt get what I wanted.

```
df1.add(df2,axis="columns")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` in both `DataFrame`s first by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for `MultiIndex` in both `DataFrames`:

```
np.random.seed(45)
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3),index=list("ABC"),columns=list("XYZ"))
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3),index=list("abc"),columns=list("XYZ"))

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.index, df2.index])
df1 = df1.reindex(mux, level=0)
df2 = df2.reindex(mux, level=1)
print (df1)
            X         Y         Z
A a  0.026375  0.260322 -0.395146
  b  0.026375  0.260322 -0.395146
  c  0.026375  0.260322 -0.395146
B a -0.204301 -1.271633 -2.596879
  b -0.204301 -1.271633 -2.596879
  c -0.204301 -1.271633 -2.596879
C a  0.289681 -0.873305  0.394073
  b  0.289681 -0.873305  0.394073
  c  0.289681 -0.873305  0.394073

print (df2)
            X         Y         Z
A a  0.935106 -0.015685  0.259596
  b -1.473314  0.801927 -1.750752
  c -0.495052 -1.008601  0.025244
B a  0.935106 -0.015685  0.259596
  b -1.473314  0.801927 -1.750752
  c -0.495052 -1.008601  0.025244
C a  0.935106 -0.015685  0.259596
  b -1.473314  0.801927 -1.750752
  c -0.495052 -1.008601  0.025244
```

---

```
df3 = df1.add(df2,axis="columns")
print (df3)
            X         Y         Z
A a  0.961480  0.244637 -0.135550
  b -1.446939  1.062248 -2.145898
  c -0.468677 -0.748279 -0.369901
B a  0.730805 -1.287317 -2.337283
  b -1.677615 -0.469706 -4.347631
  c -0.699353 -2.280233 -2.571634
C a  1.224786 -0.888989  0.653669
  b -1.183633 -0.071378 -1.356680
  c -0.205371 -1.881905  0.419317
```

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

IIUIC, Here's one way, using `merge` on temporary `k`, resulting in every index combination and then `groupby` on columns.

```
In [192]: (df1.reset_index().assign(k='k').merge(df2.assign(k='k').reset_index(), on=['k'])
              .set_index(['index_x', 'index_y'])
              .groupby(lambda x:x.split('_')[0], axis=1)
              .sum()
              .drop('k', 1))
Out[192]:
                        X         Y         Z
index_x index_y
A       a       -2.281005 -1.606760 -0.853813
        b       -2.683788 -2.487876  2.471459
        c       -0.333471 -2.155734  1.688883
B       a       -0.790146  0.074629 -2.368680
        b       -1.192928 -0.806487  0.956592
        c        1.157388 -0.474345  0.174017
C       a       -2.114412  0.100412 -2.352661
        b       -2.517195 -0.780704  0.972611
        c       -0.166878 -0.448562  0.190036
```

Details

```
In [193]: df1
Out[193]:
          X         Y         Z
A -1.087129 -1.264522  1.147618
B  0.403731  0.416867 -0.367249
C -0.920536  0.442650 -0.351229

In [194]: df2
Out[194]:
          X         Y         Z
a -1.193876 -0.342237 -2.001431
b -1.596659 -1.223354  1.323841
c  0.753658 -0.891211  0.541265

In [196]: (df1.reset_index().assign(k='k').merge(df2.assign(k='k').reset_index(), on=['k'])
              .set_index(['index_x', 'index_y']))
Out[196]:
                      X_x       Y_x       Z_x  k       X_y       Y_y       Z_y
index_x index_y
A       a       -1.087129 -1.264522  1.147618  k -1.193876 -0.342237 -2.001431
        b       -1.087129 -1.264522  1.147618  k -1.596659 -1.223354  1.323841
        c       -1.087129 -1.264522  1.147618  k  0.753658 -0.891211  0.541265
B       a        0.403731  0.416867 -0.367249  k -1.193876 -0.342237 -2.001431
        b        0.403731  0.416867 -0.367249  k -1.596659 -1.223354  1.323841
        c        0.403731  0.416867 -0.367249  k  0.753658 -0.891211  0.541265
C       a       -0.920536  0.442650 -0.351229  k -1.193876 -0.342237 -2.001431
        b       -0.920536  0.442650 -0.351229  k -1.596659 -1.223354  1.323841
        c       -0.920536  0.442650 -0.351229  k  0.753658 -0.891211  0.541265
```